# where use method onItemSelected

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i have two classes: `fragment` and `MyListAdapter`(array adapter).

In which class i must use method `onItemSelected`?

In `MyListAdapter` doesn't work.....

this is my code:

ARRAY ADAPTER:

```
public  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  {
    Spinner spinner;

    /*public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }*/

    public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
    }





        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            System.out.println("ciao");

            spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getContext(),
                    R.array.country_arrays,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

/*
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
*/
           /*     @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Spinner spinner = null;
                   // String selState = (String) ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem();

                    spinner.setSelection(position);
                    String selState = (String) ( parent).getSelectedItem();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            parent.getContext(),
                            "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }


            });*/



            return row;
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinner.setSelection(position);
        String selState = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(selState);
        Toast.makeText(
                getContext(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       /* Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


   /* @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(selState);
        Toast.makeText(
                getContext(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }*/

    }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();

        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to implement `setOnItemSelectedListener` or `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Are you getting error? or onItemSelected not working?

Comment: onItemSelected not working

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: no.......toast not appear

Comment: can you help me? @VV

Comment: can you add  spinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this); after  spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);

Comment: where? in which class?

Comment: i think that it is not a good answer to fix my iusse.....

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for Adapter file.

```
public  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter   {
Spinner spinner;

/*public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}*/

public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        System.out.println("ciao");

        spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getContext(),
                R.array.country_arrays,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Spinner spinner = null;
                String selState = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

           //     spinner.setSelection(position);
             //   String selState = (String) ( parent).getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }


        });



        return row;
    }

}
```

Comment: @help me please...

Comment: doesn't work............

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what error you got?

Comment: i not have error but toast not appear with choice

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: doesn't work................

Comment: if i use itemselected into fragment with list view?

Comment: Yes that is also work. But comment out click listner in Adapter view.

Comment: and what is the code in fragment?

Comment: I think you just need a spinner for you view. RIght?

Comment: But spinner is into adapter

Comment: In adapter there is any other item?

Comment: how can write in fragment?

Comment: Then just put spinner directly into your fragment. It will be easy for you.

Comment: mmmm can you write me code,please?

Comment: See this example. https://gist.github.com/mauliksoni/8151336

Comment: this example not good for me because i have for each row of list view spinner.....this example is for a single spinner not into list view!

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want to make?

Comment: i have for each row of my list view a spinner.....when i select a checkbox appear spinner and when i choice an object into spinner toast must say "you click on...."

Comment: can you help me,please?

Comment: On click of spinner item what you get now? for example you click on item what is there in toast? Can you share that screenshot?

Comment: toast not appear....

Comment: and in log not appear nothing

Comment: Please give me screenshot of your screen so i can understand what you are trying to implement...

Comment: ok, i posted screenshot

Comment: do ou understand what i want do?